# looking for help with the proof of the sum of 3 consecutive natural numbers

Tags: solution-verification, proof-explanation

prove that the sum of the cubes of any 3 consecutive natural numbers is a multiple of 3.

I know that I would start this by the process of induction,

however I am not sure how to go about this. I would appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Why not just write out $(n-1)^3+n^3+(n+1)^3$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $n-1, n, n+1$ be three consecutive natural numbers. Then

$$
(n-1)^3+n^3+(n+1)^3=n^3-3n^2+3n-1+n^3+n^3+3n^2+3n+1=3n^3+6n 
$$

which is clearly a multiple of $3$

Comment: (+1) Clever and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Although induction approach plausible it is not necessary.

For any integer $x$, $x^3 \equiv x \pmod{3}.$

Further, any integer $x$ will have a residue $\pmod{3}$ that is some element in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Therefore, all that you have to do, is check each of the 3 residues for $x$ separately.

So, the direct (non-inductive) approach only involves 3 separate cases.

Comment: You can make this clever noticing three consecutive numbers will always have residues $0,1,2$ in cycling order (i.e. $0,1,2$ or $1,2,0$ or $2,0,1$) so the sum of their cubes modulo $3$ is always $0^3+1^3+2^3\equiv 9\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Comment: @zwim Yes, but when I wrote the answer, there were no other answers, and the OP had not shown any work.  So, I was trying to leave the OP some work to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a simpler way by avoiding induction too.
Just take three consecutive numbers as $k, k+1, k+2$, cube each of them using the binomial theorem, and get the resultant sum. You will get a factor of 3 in the resultant summation, and you can proceed it from here.